ORACLE Sqlplus-connection problem wehn running in local container
I am trying to run sqlplus inside a container on my windows-machine, and I cannot connect to the database using the TNS-Name. The connection works when I connect through the IP-Adress or the hostname.
There are some funny things:

the same container gets deployed to an openshift-cluster, and there everything works fine with the TNS-Name
when I use strace on calling sqlplus, the TNS-Name also starts working
when I use a sqlnet.ora-file and set TRACE_LEVEL_CLIENT = 16 the connection also works (without strace)

This means: the tnsnames.ora is working, and there are no network-problems (otherwise I should not be able to connect to the databse at all).
I can work around the problem by using the hostname or setting the trace level, but I want to understand why I cannot use the TNS-Name, and why it is working on the openshift-cluster. Has anybody ideas what the problem could be?
The logfile of the client is not of much help:
Fatal NI connect error 12537 [Time : 14-MAI-2024 10:57:55] [NS errors [12537:TNS-12537: TNS: Verbindung beendet] 12560] [NT errors [507 Verbindung beendet] 0] [Oracle errors [0 ] 0] [Connecting to: (DESCRIPTION=(FAILOVER=true)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))(LOAD_BALANCE=yes)(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=MYSERVICE)(FAILOVER_MODE=(TYPE=select)(METHOD=basic))(CID=(PROGRAM=sqlplus)(HOST=94e89478812b)(USER=root))(CONNECTION_ID=GGjgw8pUAIzgYwMAEqwV0Q==)))] [PID: 140]
Here is a part of the dockerfile:
RUN mkdir -p /opt/oracle && \
    cd /opt/oracle &&\
    wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/instantclient-basic-linuxx64.zip -O instantclient.zip && \
    wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/instantclient-sdk-linuxx64.zip -O instantclient-sdk.zip && \
    wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/instantclient-sqlplus-linuxx64.zip -O sqlplus.zip

WORKDIR /opt/oracle

# Oracle Instant Client und SDK entpacken
RUN unzip -o instantclient.zip -d /opt/oracle && \
    unzip -o instantclient-sdk.zip -d /opt/oracle && \
    unzip -o sqlplus.zip -d /opt/oracle && \
    mv instantclient_* instantclient

# Umgebungsvariablen setzen
ENV ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/instantclient
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$ORACLE_HOME:/usr/local/bin
ENV C_INCLUDE_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/sdk/include
ENV CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/sdk/include
ENV NLS_LANG=GERMAN_AUSTRIA.UTF8
ENV TNS_ADMIN=/app


No ideas out there?
